# how to toggle item on semantic ui Multiple Selection dropdown by clicking label?

Tags: semantic-ui, multipleselection

I tried to use semantic ui's multiple selection dropdown.
And I want to remove selected items by clicking 'label' classed a tag, not "delete icon" classed i tag.
Is there any way to do that?

```
<?php
    $parts = [
        ...
    ];
?>
<div class="ui segment field">
    <label>subparts</label>
    <select name="gsp[]" class="ui dropdown fluid" multiple="">
        <option value="">select</option>
<?php foreach($parts as $v){ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $v?>"><?php echo $v?></option>
<?php } ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `onLabelSelect`.

```
$('.ui.multiple.dropdown').dropdown({
    onLabelSelect: function (label) {
        var $label = $(label);

        $label.parent('.ui.multiple.dropdown')
            .dropdown('remove selected', $label.data('value'));
    } 
})
```